# How to unmarshalling xml with different tags

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've got this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
      <beer>some beer</beer>
      <beer>some another beer</beer>
      <food>some food</food>
      <food>some another food</food>
  </root>`enter code here`
```

To unmarshalling this xml with JAXB I'm using this source:

```
@XmlElement(name="beer")
public void setKey(Set<String> key)
{
    this.key = key;
}
```

When I unmarshalling xml for *Set* I've receive the result: "some beer" and "some another beer", because the anotation and the tag name. 
So how can I parse all childs from the *"root"* tag. 
i.e. result in Set have to be: some beer, some another beer, some food, some another food.

Thanks previously for the time spend for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need JAXB for this? 
If so, maybe something like this will help:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "beer",
    "food"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Beer> beer;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<Food> food;

public List<Beer> getBeer() {
        if (beer == null) {
            beer = new ArrayList<Beer>();
        }
        return this.beer;
    }

public List<Food> getFood() {
        if (food == null) {
            food = new ArrayList<Food>();
        }
        return this.food;
    }

}
```

Also you need to create Food and Beer classes with getters and setters. For lists there is no need to create setters, because you can use add() after getter. 
But I recommend to use DOM for this task.